# Why can't I open programs after watching youtube videos for a while?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, youtube

I have recently built a new PC, and it worked fine for a while (1-2 months of no problems whatsoever). However in the recent weeks I noticed that after I watched some youtube videos and closed everything, I can no longer do anything except move the mouse and expand the Startup Menu. If I click on any of the programs on the Start Menu or type a program on the Run text box, it won't open anything.  I can't open taskmgr, or windows explorer, or even shut down the PC. I don't have anything else running when I'm watching videos except ZoneAlarm and Avast.

The only workaround I can do when this happens is a forced shutdown (holding the power button of my PC), and restart if I wanted to do anything more.  But this happens a lot - about 4-5 times a week so I'm worried it would fry up my hardware if I keep on doing this.

- OS: Windows 7
- Other Installed Software: Open Office, Tropico 4 game, Adobe Photoshop
- Browser used: Google Chrome
- Hardware:

  - CPU: i7 2600K
  - RAM: 16 GB
  - Motherboard: Asus P8Z68-V GEN3
  - Hard Drive: 120GB Corsair Force GT SSD
  - Graphics: 2047MB GeForce GTX 560 Ti

Comment: I have also tried using either the integrated Google Chrome Flash plugin, or the System plugin for Flash.  My Google Chrome and Flash are also up-to-date.

Comment: My first thoughts are: Can you try this in Firefox and Internet Explorer to see if the behavior is the same. That might isolate it to a browser-specific issue. My other thought is: have you run a full antivirus scan and anti-malware scan recently? I'd use MalwareBytes and a second AV such as Nod32 30-day free trial: http://www.eset.com/us/download/free-trial/.

Comment: I guess i'll try using firefox for the meantime and respond if i notice the same error.  I run a full scan once a week using Avast

Comment: does it ever happen with other programs that may chew up a large amount of RAM?

Comment: It doesnt happen when I'm playing Tropico 4.  I tried again last night using Firefox, but it went to BSOD.

Comment: Bug Check Code: 0x0bad0020
Parameter 1: 00000000`00000008
Parameter 2: fffff880`0cec1990
Parameter 3: fffff880`0cec1138
Parameter 4: fffff880`0cec0990

Caused by Driver: klif.sys
Caused by Address: klif.sys+555b7

Crash Address: ntoskrnl.exe+7f1c0

Comment: The BSOD this happened after watching 6 videos at 720p (does it matter)?  And then this morning, computer stopped responding again while just using YM and google chrome (no videos - just wikipedia).  Again i can't click links, open programs, etc, so I had to force reboot.

Comment: I also noticed it to happen when I'm using Netflix.  I can't complete a full movie without the computer crashing.

Comment: You might try entirely disabling either Avast or ZoneAlarm, and seeing if that fixes your problem.  It typically isn't recommended to run two or more security suites concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Did your try to **completely uninstall** Google Chrome and then re-install it?

There is an article: [How to repair my Google Chrome](http://www.chromefans.org/chrome-tutorial/how-to-repair-my-google-chrome.htm)